# Generate nice url with Router navigate

Tags: angular

I am using the `navigate` function from `Router` class to generate a URL from a component:

```
this.router.navigate(['/menu'], { queryParams: { level, parent: name } });
```

It works fine with setting `this.route.params`, but my URL looks like `/menu?level=2&parent=A`, which is very ugly.

I would like the url to look like: `/menu/2/A`.

I have replaced `router.navigate` with `location.go('/menu/' + level + '/' + name)` (Location from `@angular/common`). The problem is that it doesn't update `this.route.params`.

Any suggestion how I can get nice URL and update `route.params`?

Routes config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'menu/:level/:parent', component: MenuComponent, pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent, pathMatch : 'full'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this?

```
this.router.navigate(['/menu', { level, parent: name }]);
```

Docs:
https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: Then my url is looking like this `/menu;level=2;parent=A`

Comment: could you add your Routes config where you define /menu route?

Comment: I added it now. Please check